# When should we undo downvote?

Tags: discussion, down-votes, undo

I downvote very rarely, sometimes the answer has been edited after to a good answer, and I will like to undo it. But sometimes, although the answer is corrected now, I may feel it's not right to just undo the downvote. So my question is: is there a general guideline of when/to which extent should we undo the downvote?

Some examples I feel not right/not 100% comfortable to undo:

- https://stackoverflow.com/a/20992824/352101
- https://stackoverflow.com/a/20992121/352101

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You votes are your own, you are allowed to vote and retract votes as you see fit.

I'd undo votes using the same criteria as for downvoting a post in the first place. If you had not yet voted, would you still downvote the post now, after the edit? If so, leave the downvote in place and don't undo the vote.

Answer (score 3):

Whether or not you undo the downvote is entirely up to your judgement of how the question was improved (if at all).

Voting is anonymous, so you do not necessarily need to answer to how you vote.